# facebook wall links fetching

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-wall

I've been using the FQL to try and retrieve wall likes and links (that belong to a user that added my app), and the results I'm getting in return are limited/partial.

I've been extracting them through the queries:

```
SELECT action_links,attachment,message,action_links,likes 
            FROM stream WHERE  source_id=".$this->user."

SELECT url,t itle FROM link WHERE owner=".$this->user
```

But some of the owner's likes are not being extracted via these methods. Does anyone have any idea where else (or in what different conditions) a more FULL result set might be available?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Graph API for the fastest way to get this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

The links are available at /[UID]/links and the likes at /[UID]/likes and are returned in JSON format

Some will be visible with a basic access token (those which are set to 'public') and you can get the rest if you request the user_likes and read_stream permissions)

Try it out in the Graph Explorer at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

To answer your question in the context of FQL, check you have the right permissions (the two i mentioned above will also apply to FQL) but basically you're already looking at the right tables

Comment: I've managed to limit problematic wall posts to those that are generally "XXX likes a link." (XXX being the user itself). However, this only happens to SOME of them. for examples, when liking an IMDB page, it goes to likes, but other pages do NOT and also don't appear in the STREAM (not as links not as stream entities). 
I have tried /likes and /links, as well as the FQL tables mentioned in my original post. 
Anyone has any further ideas as to what's filtering the unfetched objects?

Comment: Do you definitely have the 'read_stream' and user_likes permissions? Without them you may still see a subset of posts with privacy set to 'everyone'

Comment: yes, I have them both (and 2 others that are not related to this functionality)